# Creating Dynamic Fetch Expression

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

[image: DomainModel]
I have an object graph like this. I would like to dynamically build fetch expression in Linq to NHibernate so that I get all object graph in one SQL call,

I think, I can write fetch like this, which would do that job,

```
IQueryable<Customer> lists = customerPersister.Query()
        .Where(item => item.Id == id)
        .FetchMany(item => item.LineOfBusiness)
        .FetchMany(i2 => i2.Address)
        .FetchMany(i3 => i3.Orders)
        .ThenFetchMany(i4=>i4.OrderItems) ;
```

But I don't need all these object graph always. Sometime I need `Customer` and `Address`, sometime `Customer` and `LinesOfBusiness` or sometime `Customer` and `Orders`.

Is there anyway, I can dynamically build this fetch expression?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply expand the query as needed:

```
IQueryable<Customer> lists = customerPersister.Query().Where(item => item.Id == id);
if (needLinesOfBusiness)
    lists = lists.FetchMany(item => item.LineOfBusiness);
if (needAddress)
    lists = lists.FetchMany(item => item.Address);
if (needOrders || needOrderItems)
{
    if (!needOrderItems)
        lists = lists.FetchMany(item => item.Orders);
    else
        lists = lists.FetchMany(item => item.Orders).ThenFetchMany(order => order.Items);
}
```

The only trick is that `ThenFetchMany` doesn't work on an `IQueryable<Customer>`, so you need to include the order and the order items in one go.